# git sync fork history with upstream before pull request

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have a strange setup with my git repos in order to allow me to contribute to a project on github from gitlab (what my workplace uses). The original public github repo is the upstream of a fork on my personal github, which is then the upstream of a fork on gitlab. When I want to do a pull request, I push my changes from gitlab to the intermediary github and do a pull request from there. This is all because you can't do a pull request from gitlab to github directly.

I've successfully been using this and have completed a pull request with the parent project. I'm ready for another pull request, but am confused about why so many commits are showing up in the pull request draft. All of the merges from upstream and all of the commits that were pushed to the parent project are showing up in the pull request.

I only want the relevant last 3 commits to be in the pull request. All of my code is up-to-date with the parent master (except for the most recent 3 commits). Should I have been using rebase? I've never used it and am hesitant.

```
parent  --------------------  *-*-*-*
 \                           /       \              pull request has more than 3 most recent gitlab commits
  \                         /         \            / 
   github fork ----------  * --------- * -------- *
    \                     /             \        /
     \                   /               \      /
      gitlab fork *-*-*-*-----------------*-*-*
```